Minimum loft size for positive input ventilation?
I'm having our roof redone and would like most of it to be vaulted.  However, I'd also like a positive input ventilation unit to increase air movement through the house and reduce condensation.  I'm thinking part of the loft could be preserved above the bathroom.
How large does a loft space have to be in order for the PIV unit to be effective?  Is there a minimum size, besides the size of the unit itself?

Usually ventilation does not take much space, but depending on location, insulation does take space.
